# Automatically publish application in eclipse without keeping eclipse window active

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat8, spring-tool-suite

I am facing a weird problem.

I have a requirement in which I have to deploy application on tomcat of eclipse whereas do coding in `Visual Studio Code`.

I have deployed an application on tomcat of eclipse and 
have enabled "`Automatically publish when resources change`".

Application gets published whenever I change any file from eclipse.

But when I change the same file from Visual Studio code, the it does not get auto-published.

But when I open(or keep active) the eclipse window, changes get auto-published.

Is there any way to which will allow me to code in `Visual Studio Code` and auto-publish that application on tomcat of eclipse.

**Note:** The application must be deployed on tomcat of eclipse only. It should not be deployed externally.

Comment: Eclipse works with an abstraction of the file system and therefore doesn't trigger a refresh automatically if a file on the system changes. But there is an option to enable that in the preferences.

Comment: Please mention the which option in preferences. Please elaborate

Comment: Open the preferences ("Window >> Preferences") then type "Refresh" in the search box and I think you'll find the setting martin is referring to.

Comment: @Kris I am not able to find that option. Can you please post the answer with proper steps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the preferences via "Window >> Preferences" then type "refresh" in the searchbox and you will find the preferences under "General >> workspace". Make sure to enable "Refresh using native hooks or polling" and "Refresh on access" (maybe enabling one of them is enough but I always enable both to make sure).

[image]

Comment: It works well. Thank you. I edit js and html in vscode. Eclipse is used for Tomcat servers.

Comment: @bbh That's actually good idea. I should try that some time